# how can i show firebase firestore data to a ResponsiveGridView() or add firestore data to a List<> in Flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I can show my firebase data to a ListView.builder(). But I can't understand how can I show my data to a ResponsiveGridList().

**Here is the code of *MyListView.dart* file  where I can load firebase data**

```
  Future productData;

  Future getData() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("product").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    productData = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: productData,
      builder: ( _ , snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Text("Loading...");
        }else{
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ListTile( title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["title"]),);
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I want to use [responsiveGridList()](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_grid) in the place of ListView.builder().

**Here is the ResponsiveGridList()**

```
List<String> list = ["title 1", "title 2", "title 3"];

ResponsiveGridList(
            scroll: false,
            desiredItemWidth: 200,
            minSpacing: 0,
    
            children: list.map((i) {
    
              return Container(child: Text(i),);
    
            }).toList()
    
        );
```

I have tried to load data to my RespnsiveGridlist but can't.
Is there any option to add data to a list and then I can show the list of data into a listView.
The ResponsiveGridList() requires a list of data.

Comment: please give me an answer